# If multiple accounts own different DLCs for a game, can every account in the console use them?

Tags: ps4, psn

Let's say that my friend has DLC **A** and **B** for game **X** on his account, and I want to buy the DLC **C** with my own account:

- Would both account be able to use all of the DLCs? (both accounts have the console activated as primary)
- What about other users in the same console?
- Does this change between Free to Play games and Full Paid Games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible on a single console with both accounts activated as primary (as you've mentioned). The DLC from both accounts will be usable in the game, and available to the other users on the account too.

You would have to check individually for the game concerned, but the PlayStation Store states that the license allows you to use the DLC and Games on any console where you are activated as primary (which means any other user can use the same content), and one other console you have signed into, but only for your user account on that console.